# Using targeting (eligibility criterion) as an instrument

Tags: instrumental-variables

I want to know if it is economterically sound to use the targeting criterion (eligibility criterion) as an IV for a natural experiment.

I have read a UCT program that uses a certain set of indicators to determine overall household eligibility (to be considered for the program). My RHS variable is child educational outcome (whether or not a child is enrolled at school).

I am trying to find the casual impact between this UCT program and child enrollment levels. Some one suggested using the eligibility criterion as an IV. It makes sense because the set of indicators used for determining eligibility (such as household assets, type of sanitation facility etc) are correlated with receiving the UCT; but are uncorrelated with the child enrollment levels.

I've tried searching for similar papers/studies that have used this approach. But haven't come across any so far. Does this approach make sense? Also would really appreciate it if they can quote some work/paper/study that has a program's targeting/eligibility criterion as an IV.

thanks! Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Well by their very nature, targeting criteria would be linked to individual's characteristics, and hence potentially to your outcome? If on the other side you can (re)construct an eligibility score, you could use it in a regression discontinuity context, as a local IV maybe?   Btw, what is an UCT?

Comment: Hi! A UCT is an unconditional cash transfer- as cash transfer that comes with no strings attached. The RD design is one possibility that I did consider earlier, but it didn't work out right. Can you please elaborate on the local IV or suggest papers on that design? Will really appreciated it! @matifou

Comment: I just meant the standard fuzzy RD case where your forcing variable does not perfectly predict the outcome and hence is seen as a local IV (hence not local IV à la Heckmann).

Comment: Yes! I understand what you mean now! Great! Thanks!